# Accessing JSON objects via PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm getting response from an API as JSON object, below is the JSON object that I am getting. I am trying to access some fields from it, but somehow, it is not working.

I am very new to API and JSON, so any help will be great.

```
{
  [
    "result"
  ]=>object(stdClass)#5(17){
    [
      "id"
    ]=>string(32)"f3add916cd34d635cb88452f4b024028"[
      "name"
    ]=>string(12)"domain.com"[
      "status"
    ]=>string(7)"pending"[
      "paused"
    ]=>bool(false)[
      "type"
    ]=>string(4)"full"[
      "development_mode"
    ]=>int(0)[
      "name_servers"
    ]=>array(2){
      [
        0
      ]=>string(21)"asa.ns.cloudflare.com"[
        1
      ]=>string(22)"gabe.ns.cloudflare.com"
    }[
      "original_name_servers"
    ]=>array(2){
      [
        0
      ]=>string(26)"dns1.registrar-servers.com"[
        1
      ]=>string(26)"dns2.registrar-servers.com"
    }[
      "original_registrar"
    ]=>NULL[
      "original_dnshost"
    ]=>NULL[
      "modified_on"
    ]=>string(27)"2017-08-22T10:03:26.537122Z"[
      "created_on"
    ]=>string(27)"2017-08-22T10:03:26.537122Z"[
      "meta"
    ]=>object(stdClass)#6(6){
      [
        "step"
      ]=>int(4)[
        "wildcard_proxiable"
      ]=>bool(false)[
        "custom_certificate_quota"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "page_rule_quota"
      ]=>int(3)[
        "phishing_detected"
      ]=>bool(false)[
        "multiple_railguns_allowed"
      ]=>bool(false)
    }[
      "owner"
    ]=>object(stdClass)#7(3){
      [
        "id"
      ]=>string(32)"a1a492e3c3345ff4c84a569838d56967"[
        "type"
      ]=>string(4)"user"[
        "email"
      ]=>string(20)"email.com"
    }[
      "account"
    ]=>object(stdClass)#8(1){
      [
        "id"
      ]=>string(32)"myID"
    }[
      "permissions"
    ]=>array(22){
      [
        0
      ]=>string(15)"#analytics:read"[
        1
      ]=>string(9)"#app:edit"[
        2
      ]=>string(13)"#billing:edit"[
        3
      ]=>string(13)"#billing:read"[
        4
      ]=>string(17)"#cache_purge:edit"[
        5
      ]=>string(17)"#dns_records:edit"[
        6
      ]=>string(17)"#dns_records:read"[
        7
      ]=>string(8)"#lb:edit"[
        8
      ]=>string(8)"#lb:read"[
        9
      ]=>string(10)"#logs:read"[
        10
      ]=>string(12)"#member:edit"[
        11
      ]=>string(12)"#member:read"[
        12
      ]=>string(18)"#organization:edit"[
        13
      ]=>string(18)"#organization:read"[
        14
      ]=>string(9)"#ssl:edit"[
        15
      ]=>string(9)"#ssl:read"[
        16
      ]=>string(9)"#waf:edit"[
        17
      ]=>string(9)"#waf:read"[
        18
      ]=>string(10)"#zone:edit"[
        19
      ]=>string(10)"#zone:read"[
        20
      ]=>string(19)"#zone_settings:edit"[
        21
      ]=>string(19)"#zone_settings:read"
    }[
      "plan"
    ]=>object(stdClass)#9(10){
      [
        "id"
      ]=>string(32)"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"[
        "name"
      ]=>string(12)"Free Website"[
        "price"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "currency"
      ]=>string(3)"USD"[
        "frequency"
      ]=>string(0)""[
        "is_subscribed"
      ]=>bool(true)[
        "can_subscribe"
      ]=>bool(false)[
        "legacy_id"
      ]=>string(4)"free"[
        "legacy_discount"
      ]=>bool(false)[
        "externally_managed"
      ]=>bool(false)
    }
  }[
    "success"
  ]=>bool(true)[
    "errors"
  ]=>array(0){

  }[
    "messages"
  ]=>array(0){

  }
}
```

How do I access the **ID** variable within **"result"** or both the nameservers?

I've tried this, doesn't work.

```
foreach($a as $b=>$c)
    {
        echo $b . "=" . $c;
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

$a contains the json object.
Please guide me right direction.

Comment: Are you running a `json_decode` on your response?

Comment: $jsonarray = json_deocde($jsonObject,true); Use this code you  get json array

Comment: I am getting an object and not string.
If I run it, I get :-

`json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: May you please post the method on how you are getting `$a`

Comment: It's via an API


$a = $dns->create("domain.net");

Comment: can you post the results of `print_r($a)` please, or is that the result from the OP?

Comment: dump $a like echo "<pre>"; print_r($a); so we can trace easily, secondly which key you want to access